# returning a count of the number of slots in the array that contain a value that is equal to the index of the slot

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that will return the number of slots in the array that contain a value that is equal to the index of the slot, after random numbers are generated, then prints each element of the array on a separate line with an asterix. (Suppose to look like this:)

```
Enter the array size: 4
a[0] = 2
a[1] = 1 *
a[2] = 0
a[3] = 2
There are 1 slots where the index is the same as the value.
```

But I am failing miserably, any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int i;
    System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
            i = in.nextInt();

}

/**
 * Fills an array with random integers in the range from zero to one less
 * than the array size.
 * 
 * @param array
 *            the array to fill with random integers
 */
public static void fillArrayWithRandomInts(int array[]) {
    java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random(13);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        array[i] = (int) (random.nextDouble() * array.length);
}

public static int countSlotsWithIndexEqualToValue(int array[]) {

    int[] value = new int[13];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (value[13] == array[13])
            ;

    }
    return value[13];

}

public static void printArray(int array[]) {

}

}
```

Comment: What does "failing miserably" mean? Error or problem description, where art thou?

Comment: In your for loop, you have to compare the index `i` with the value in `array[]`

Comment: It doesn't even give me an error. It just says "Enter the array size:" and then when I enter something, it returns nothing.

Comment: @user2918429 You need to call the methods in your main too.

Comment: I had: if (i[13] == array[13])        but then eclipse tells me: the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

Comment: @user2918429 i is an `int`, not an `int[]`.

Comment: I know that I have to call the methods in my main, but I hadn't gotten that far yet :) just stuck on the for loop still

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the check and printing in the same method. And in case you need to keep a count of how many such combinations are there, you need to add a counter.

```
public static void countSlotsAndPrint(int[] a) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("a[" + i + "] = " + a[i]); // print the array as per required
        if (i == array[i]){
            System.out.println(" *"); // if index is equal to the value, then print the *            
            counter++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(); // blank line to go to the next line
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + counter + " slots where the index is the same as the value.");
}
```

Comment: add an "else --> println()" so that it doesn't stay on the sane line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k;
    int[] arrayOfValues;
    ArrayList<Integer> answer;

    answer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
    k = in.nextInt();

    // create an array
    arrayOfValues = new int[k];
    // fill an array
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; ++i)
        arrayOfValues[i] = (int) (Math.random() * arrayOfValues.length);
    // to see an array -> uncomment
    /*
    System.out.println("Random array");
    for(int i : arrayOfValues) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    */
    // check an array
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
        if(arrayOfValues[i] == i) {
            answer.add(i);
        }
    }
    // printing result
    System.out.println("Your answer is:");
    for(int i : answer) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

i think, you are looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do, you don't even need an array (unless that's the point of the exercise, in which case the exercise is flawed).

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int inputSize;
        System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
        inputSize = in.nextInt();

        if (inputSize > 0)
        {    
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++)
            {           
                randomNumber = random.nextInt() % inputSize;

                System.out.print("a[" + i + "] = " + randomNumber);

                if (randomNumber == i)
                {
                    System.out.println(" *");
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("There are " + count + " slots where the index is the same as the value.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is the point of the exercise. Why is it flawed, just out of curiosity. Because it's not the most efficient way?

Comment: because an exercise which is supposed to teach you how to use arrays should give you a problem that can't be easily solved without them. For instance: receive X numbers as input, and then sort them from highest to lowest.